# Returning Garbage value c++

Tags: c++

I have a method that is suppose to return a garbage value if an item in a tree is not found. All I'm getting though is a runtime exception: "garbage is being used without being defined"

```
ItemType BstClass::rRetrieve(node* trav, KeyType key, bool& inTree)
{
    if(trav == NULL)
    {
        inTree = false;
        ItemType garbage;
        return garbage - 1;
    }
    if(trav->data.key == key)
    { 
        inTree = true;
        return trav->data; 
    }
    else if (key < trav->data.key) 
        return(rRetrieve(trav->left, key, inTree)); 
    else
        return(rRetrieve(trav->right, key, inTree)); 
}// end rRetrieve
```

Is there another way to do this? We were told to use

```
return garbage - 1;
```

Comment: Can you please show the whole code that you're referring to? We don't know what the function is supposed to return, for starters.

Comment: Post all the relevant code (i.e. the complete function), using copy and paste.

Comment: And ItemType declaration may also be of help.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "garbage value". ISO C++ standard defines the value of an unitialized POD-type variable as "indeterminate", and that may mean anything, including a trap representation; consequently, accessing it results in undefined behavior (i.e. a conformant implementation can compile your program and produce code that crashes on `return`, for example).

Comment: Maybe you should use a const definition.
const int GARBAGE_VALUE = -1;

then return GARBAGE_VALUE when item not found.

Comment: Who assigns homework like this, requiring the invoking of undefined behavior?  It would be worth knowing, in case we ever have the bad fortune to encounter the assigner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on details of class ItemType which we don't have access to.  Depending on what sort of operations you can do with ItemType and what sort of requirements you have about the 'garbage' value, you theoretically have a couple of choices.

1. Directly construct and return your 'garbage' value.  Something like `return ItemType(-1);` or `return ItemType(NULL);`  Specifically how you construct a `garbage` value depends on what constructors you have and their semantics.
2. Perhaps you shouldn't even care about the specific value.  Since you have the `inTree` output variable indicating when you haven't found a value, then perhaps just return the default value `return ItemType();`  This is not as robust because the code is no longer redundant (i.e. for method 1, if the caller does not check `inTree` then hopefully using the 'garbage' will prevent the code from doing something wrong).

Answer (score 4):

Without more info this is only a guess but how about:

```
ItemType garbage = -1;
return garbage;
```

Comment: "blind guess" quality, but yeah there is too little information to make a good answer

Answer (score 2):

A garbage value is any value NOT in the expected set of valid values that a function can return but is in the set of values that the function MAY return.  For instance, if your tree contains positive numbers and you return a signed int from your tree search function, then a garbage value is any negative number.  In this case I would return -1 as the garbage value.

For your case, I would probably replace the line

```
return garbage - 1;
```

with

```
return garbage = (ItemType)NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably way out of scope, but you could use boost::optional when you have no sensibile values to return. Read more at: http://cplusplus.co.il/2009/12/04/boost-optional-and-its-internals/

Answer (score 1):

The main property of "garbage" is that it can be anything. There's no way to say whether some value is garbage or not by just looking at the value. So, initialize your `garbage` variable with some arbitrarily chosen but definitive value (zero, for example) and return it.

In fact, in C++ language any attempts to manipulate the value of an uninitialized variable in general case result in undefined behavior. You simply can't return genuine garbage in C++. You *have* to initialize your variable if you want to return it or to apply arithmetic operations to it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using 'garbage' in a computation without having previously initialized it.  Perhaps

```
ItemType garbage = 0;
return garbage - 1;
```

Share and enjoy.